# How to enable buildroot gcc security build options like _FORTIFY_SOURCE and stack protector?

Tags: gcc, toolchain, buildroot

I met a requirements, the executable binary must pass the checking by https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh,

so I enabled following build configurations for my toolchain gcc:

```
_D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-all
```

but it didn't output any warning msgs during the compiling, while it showed properly warning msg when i use host gcc build.

**below were my build logs**:

```
jason@linux-server:~/tmp/test$ /opt/buildroot-gcc463/usr/bin/mipsel-buildroot-linux-uclibc-gcc -Wall -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -fstack-protector-all -fpie -pie test.c -o testjason
```

there were no any warning output.

> While in host x86 gcc: In file included from
>   /usr/include/string.h:640:0,
>                    from test.c:2: In function ‘memcpy’,
>       inlined from ‘main’ at test.c:28:8: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:51:3: warning: call to
>   __builtin___memcpy_chk will always overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]    return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src,
>   __len, __bos0 (__dest));    ^ In function ‘memset’,
>       inlined from ‘main’ at test.c:35:8: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:84:3: warning: call to
>   __builtin___memset_chk will always overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]    return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __ch,
>   __len, __bos0 (__dest));

for build toolchain, I enabled libssp only in package/gcc/gcc.mk file:

Comment: HOST_GCC_COMMON_CONF_OPT = \
        --target=$(GNU_TARGET_NAME) \
        --with-sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR) \
        --disable-__cxa_atexit \
        --with-gnu-ld \
        --enable-libssp \
        --disable-multilib \
        --with-gmp=$(HOST_DIR)/usr \
        --with-mpfr=$(HOST_DIR)/usr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buildroot compiler path suggests it is GCC 4.6 targeting uclibc.  This compiler version did not have the warning you see on the host.

Furthermore, uclibc does not support `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` in any real sense, so if you must use a toolchain with that feature, uclibc is the wrong choice.